# Number of rows per group along with other summary functions

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to find number of rows and some other function after grouping by two different factors. Surprisingly, n() is not working. Is there any work around?

```r
library(dplyr)
#> Warning: package 'dplyr' was built under R version 3.6.3
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl, am) %>% 
  summarise(across(c(disp, mpg), list(m = min, a = mean)))
#> `summarise()` regrouping output by 'cyl' (override with `.groups` argument)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 6
#> # Groups:   cyl [3]
#>     cyl    am disp_m disp_a mpg_m mpg_a
#>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     4     0  120.   136.   21.5  22.9
#> 2     4     1   71.1   93.6  21.4  28.1
#> 3     6     0  168.   205.   17.8  19.1
#> 4     6     1  145    155    19.7  20.6
#> 5     8     0  276.   358.   10.4  15.0
#> 6     8     1  301    326    15    15.4

mtcars %>% group_by(cyl, am) %>% 
  summarise(across(c(disp, mpg), list(m = min, n = n())))
#> Error: Problem with `summarise()` input `..1`.
#> x Can't convert an integer vector to function
#> i Input `..1` is `across(c(disp, mpg), list(m = min, n = n()))`.
#> i The error occurred in group 1: cyl = 4, am = 0.
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: @denis no, `across` has been in the official release of `dplyr` since v1.0.0, which I believe has been on CRAN since June of this year. Maybe time to update?

Comment: @AllanCameron ok thanks. Indeed, time to update. y R version :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `length`:

```r
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl, am) %>% 
  summarise(across(c(disp, mpg), list(m = min, n = length)))
#`summarise()` regrouping output by 'cyl' (override with `.groups` argument)
## A tibble: 6 x 6
#> # Groups:   cyl [3]
#>     cyl    am disp_m disp_n mpg_m mpg_n
#>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <int> <dbl> <int>
#> 1     4     0  120.       3  21.5     3
#> 2     4     1   71.1      8  21.4     8
#> 3     6     0  168.       4  17.8     4
#> 4     6     1  145        3  19.7     3
#> 5     8     0  276.      12  10.4    12
#> 6     8     1  301        2  15       2
```

Comment: If I use a function ```min_max <- list(  min = ~min(.x, na.rm = TRUE), max = ~max(.x, na.rm = TRUE), n = ~count(.x, na.rm = TRUE))``` then it is not working.  Without ```count``` in ```min_max``` it is working.

Comment: @RamakrishnaS but doesn't `count` require a tibble or data frame for its first argument? If you try `count(rnorm(10))` you will also get an error.

Answer (score 1):

We can do

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% 
       group_by(cyl, am) %>% 
       summarise(across(c(disp, mpg), list(m = ~ min(.), n = ~n())), .groups = 'drop')
# A tibble: 6 x 6
    cyl    am disp_m disp_n mpg_m mpg_n
  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <int> <dbl> <int>
1     4     0  120.       3  21.5     3
2     4     1   71.1      8  21.4     8
3     6     0  168.       4  17.8     4
4     6     1  145        3  19.7     3
5     8     0  276.      12  10.4    12
6     8     1  301        2  15       2
```

Comment: How do we know when to use formula like ```~ min(.)``` and when to use ```min```. This part is confusing.

Comment: @RamakrishnaS When you want to pass more argument i.e `min(., na.rm = TRUE)` otherwise `min` is enough.  the `~` is just a lambda call to have more flexibility